# Hash string change case

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a `constexpr` hash string function that gets called at compile time.

I want to know, how can I convert the string to uppercase or lowercase before it is hashed?

```
constexpr unsigned long long int HashString(const char* str, unsigned long long int hash = 0)
{
    return (*str == 0) ? hash : 101 * HashString(str + 1) + *str;
}
```

Comment: Just change the second `*str` to `toupper(*str)` or `tolower(*str)` as required, *if* the string only contains alphabetic characters. Otherwise you'll have to do something more complex with `*str`, left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: The standard `toupper()` and `tolower()` functions are not themselves `constexpr`, so they can't be called inside a `constexpr` function, right?.  It would be pretty easy to write your own `constexpr` versions of them, though.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It might not be that easy if you need to support UTF-8, locales, encoding of the file...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your goal right, this is possible but with a few caveats:

- You can't actually build a new string literal in a constexpr function.  That capability does not exist in C++, so "converting the string to lowercase" is simply not possible at compile time, at least not in that specific way.
- The answer given here assumes the input is ASCII; with non-ASCII strings (UTF-8, for example) it will either not change the case of multi-byte characters, or it might even damage multi-byte characters such that a UTF-8 decoder will fail when decoding the string.

Since we can't return a new string literal out of a constexpr function, we need to be able to give the hash function a mapping function to apply to each character.  For example, here's a constexpr mapping function to convert an ASCII character to lowercase:

```
constexpr char ascii_tolower(char v) {
    return v >= 'A' && v <= 'Z' ?
        v + ('a' - 'A') :
        v;
}
```

We can also provide a simple "identity" function that maps values to themselves (if you want to hash a string as-is with no case conversion).

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T identity(T v) {
    return v;
}
```

To be able to supply these functions at compile time, we need to give this to another constexpr function as a template parameter.<sup>1</sup>  We'll make `identity` the default so that `hash_fn` can be called as though it weren't a template function, if no mapping is desired.

```
template <constexpr char (*fn)(char) = identity>
constexpr int hash_fn(char const *str) {
    return *str ? fn(*str) ^ (hash_fn<fn>(str + 1) << 3) : 0;
}
```

Now we can use this function in `constexpr` context with arbitrary mapping functions, like so:

```
constexpr int hash_a = hash_fn<ascii_tolower>("FoObAr");
constexpr int hash_b = hash_fn<ascii_tolower>("fOoBaR");
```

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34f5fe9fcc024a2f))

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that this hash function is pretty simplistic and will very easily generate collisions. It's not intended to be an example of a good hash function, just an example of the technique of using a constexpr function as a template parameter.

Comment: what do you mean that this hash function will generate collisions?

Comment: @yino I mean that the hash function is a bad hash function. Only the last 11 characters in a string actually matter; for long strings, if the last 11 characters are the same then the hash will be the same -- which is _permitted_ for a hash function, but is not _optimal._ I'd suggest using a better hash function within the paradigm of a recursive call. `hash_fn` here is only to demonstrate the technique of taking a `constexpr` function template argument and recursively computing a hash.